# How to Expand tab control's scroll bar in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, tabpage

My page in tab control has a long vertical content but the scroll bar of tab page is not long enough.
I just search on the google but i found only how to add scroll bar to tab control.
How to expand the scroll bar to fit my content?

Comment: adjust the AutoScrollMinSize property

Comment: I try this before but it doesn't work.

Comment: don't understand your problem, why could the length of the tabPage scrollBar be your problem? I doubt that its length is just a little shorter than the TabPage height.

Comment: Put a panel on your tab and your controls on the panel

Comment: @SarinSuriyakoon I assume it worked